# T-SQL: query which joins with all dependent tables and produce cartesian product

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a bunch of tables which refer to some number of other tables (zero, one, two or more).

My example tables might contain following columns:

```
Id | StatementTable1Id | StatementTable2Id | Value
```

where StatementTable1 will contain following columns:

```
Id | Name | Label
```

I wish to get all possible combinations and join all of them.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647718/sqlserver-how-to-find-dependent-tables-on-my-table/12036389#12036389) very useful (query which produce information about dependencies).

I would imagine my code as follows:

1. Prepare list of tables which I wish to query.
2. Query [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647718/sqlserver-how-to-find-dependent-tables-on-my-table/12036389#12036389) for all my tables and save results into temporary table.
3. Check maximum number of dependent tables. Prepare query template - for example if maximum number of dependent tables is equal two:

   ```
    Select 
        Id, '%Table1Name%' as Table1Name, 
        '%StatementLabelTable1%' as StatementLabelTable1,
        '%Table2Name%' as  Table2Name, 
        '%StatementLabelTable2%' as StatementLabelTable2, Value"
   ```
4. Use cursor - for each dependent table replace appropriate part with dependent table name and label of elements within it.
5. When all dependent tables have been used - replace all remaining columns with empty string.
6. add "UNION ALL" and proceed to next table
7. Run query

Could you tell me if there's any easier or better way?

Answer (score 1):

What you've listed there sounds like you'll need to do if you don't know the column details ahead of time. There's likely going to be some trial-and-error to get the details correct, but it's a good plan to start.

That being said, why on earth would you want to do such a thing? It sounds like you need to narrow down your requirements on what data is *actually* needed. Otherwise, as you add data to your database, this query and resulting data set is going to quickly become quite unwieldy (these data sets are the kinds you hear about becoming daily "door-stop reports"; no one uses them, but they never remember why it was created, so they keep running the report, and just use it as a door-stop).